# Handle children.props

Tags: reactjs, react-props, children

so, in ParentComponent I have

`<Component dropDownContent={<DropDownContent content={array} onSelect={handleSelect} />} />`

my DropDownContent looks something like this

```
return (<ul>
   {content.map((item) => 
      { return <li><button onClick={()=> onSelect(array.id)}>{array.name}</button></li>}
   )}
</ul>)
```

Can I some how do something with the `onSelect` inside `Component` even if I add `DropDownContent` as a prop to `Component`?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the *something* is? You are passing the event handler, what else do you need?

Comment: ok, so inside Component I have onSubmit when the user clicks enter, and I have state thats is "isSaving" that is set to true when that is fired. Now I want to change that so onSubmit is triggered when a button inside `DropDownContent` in clicked and onSelect is fired.

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you want to pass a function from the parent component to the child component. And when the `onSelect` component is clicked on the child, you want to call that passed function. is it correct?

Comment: Well, anything you want to execute in the parent component by being triggered in the child component would need to be passed to the child to invoke. A button in `DropDownContent` already calls `onSelect` when clicked, so it seems you just need to call `onSubmit` from your `handleSelect` callback. Is this your complete code? It still isn't completely clear (to me at least) what precisely you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to pass a function from the parent component to the child component. And when a local function inside child component is clicked, you want to call that passed function. if yes, then this is your solution:

**Note:** *I do not know exactly what code you wrote and what your component consists of. So I will give you the answer by giving a simple example to fully understand the solution.*

### In your parent component:

```
export const ParentComponent = props => {
    const handleSelect = () => console.log(`do something here`);
    return (
        <Component
            dropDownContent={
                <DropDownContent
                    content={array}
                    onSelect={() => handleSelect()}
                />}
        />
    )
}
```

### And in your child component you need to receive the passed function like below:

```
export const ChildComponent = props => {
    const handlePassedFunction = () => props.onSelect?.();
    return (<ul>
        {content.map((item) => {
                return <li>
                    <button onClick={() => handlePassedFunction(array.id)}>{array.name}</button>
                </li>
            }
        )}
    </ul>)
}
```

Comment: Tacks for your answer, but sorry, I don't follow, where is ChildComponent in the first code part? Is that the same as one of the components in there?

Comment: Here I gave an example.`ChildComponent` is actually the same as `DropDownContent` (It was my mistake not to choose the same name for both.)
The `handleSelect()` function is sent by the `onSelect` prop in the first part. In the second part, we receive and use it by the `handlePassedFunction` function.
**If my explanation is unclear, I can explain again.**